# SQL insert foreign keys if not already present while adding a new record

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Suppose I have a table 'Note':

```
PK id: int
note: varchar
FK tags: Tags[]
```

and another table 'Tags":

```
PK id: int
tag: varchar
FK note: Note[]
```

Now, if I want to add a new record, say:

```
{

 "note": "Hello World!, this is an example note",
 "tags": ['first','example']
}
```

Is there a way to do it in a single request?
Or,
Do I have to save the tags and make another request with their ids?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have an `int[]` data type. Perhaps you're using a different brand of database?

Comment: @BillKarwin sorry, I meant that they have a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a many-to-many relationship, then you should have three tables:

'Note':

```
PK id: int
note: varchar
```

'Tags':

```
PK id: int
tag: varchar
```

'NoteTags':

```
note_id int
tag_id int
PK: (note_id, tag_id)
```

Do three inserts: one insert to Note, one insert to Tags, then one insert to NoteTags for the pair of id's used to associate a given Note to a given Tag.

This is the way to represent a many-to-many relationship. [It's not a good idea to store comma-separated lists in a string.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/20860)